# Windows Store App - System Information

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

Does anyone know if it is possible to collect system information using the new Windows RT Api (windows store app).

I am looking for information like the amount of RAM available, OS Version, Screen Size. I am porting some older C# desktop code but everything I was using is no longer available.

Comment: Those things are probably not available from winRT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that link;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.aspx

But it seems currently winRT lib has not any func. to detect ram etc.

You can use C++ or C# to take these kind of information with using native (unmanagement) calls.
Take a look at here; 
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION.html

and here;
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23502/Display-device-memory-information-using-P-Invoke

And good luck...

Comment: haha thanks I will have a look. I was using some older com stuff from the win api but most of them are not available. I will have a look and update here. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow mate. If you find my answer helpfull to you, you can give points or mark as answer. And you are welcome, I glad to help...